# Vue how to get the element reference on the element in v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to conditonally render a `div` within a `card` that's a `slide` in a `carousel`. My logic is to check whether the grandparent contains the `active` `class` and then use `v-if` to determine whether it should be rendered or not however this does not seem to work, I am new to VUE but any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
    <vue-glide-slide v-for="(offer,index) in offers" :key="index" ref="offerElement">
      <div class="card">
        <img :src="offer.icon" class="card-img-top offer-image" :alt="offer.title" />
        <div class="card-body mb-5">
          <h5 class="card-title px-3">{{offer.title}}</h5>
          <div v-if="this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.contains('glide__slide--active')">
            <p class="card-text">{{offer.description}}</p>
            <button
              class="btn btn-main btn-home"
              type="button"
              @click="displayIfActive"
            >View details</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </vue-glide-slide>
```

Comment: It would be better to do this with CSS alone instead of `v-if`.

Comment: You could display none by default on the div with the v-if and then use .glide__slide--active > div >div {
 display: block;
} 

To make it rendered on the page. You can use visibility instead of you want to retain the space taken up by the div even when it is visibility: hidden;

Else use isActive prop on the offer object that you toggle on and off as you please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would be something of the like of:

```
.active h5.card-title > div {
    /*Some extra rules that override the default rules*/
}
```

But if you need to do this with Vue JS, then I would create a property in the grandparent for `active` rather than a CSS `class` and would pass that to the controls it uses and use that for your `div`.

If you prefer to have this kind of Javascript though, then this part seems to be wrong:

```
.contains('glide__slide--active')
```

You mentioned that you need to work with the `active` class instead.